# Why define return object keys as 'dummy' local variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen a code similar to the one below quite a few time recently.

Notice that `modelMapper`, `viewMapper` and `source` are defined as local variables but are unused otherwise, with the exception of serving as keys to the return object.

It is perhaps worth noting that `$parse` returns a function, and only keys that involve a returned function are declared as a local var - `itemName` isn't.

```
parse:function (input) {

  var match = input.match(TYPEAHEAD_REGEXP), modelMapper, viewMapper, source;
  if (!match) {
    throw new Error("Error...");
  }

  return {
    itemName:match[3],
    source:$parse(match[4]),
    viewMapper:$parse(match[2] || match[1]),
    modelMapper:$parse(match[1])
  };
}
```

What is the purpose of defining these local var?

Comment: Use either jslint or jshint. Linter will tell you a lot about this code and its author :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko jslint is actually fine with this `var dummy = function () { 'use strict'; return { kill: function () { return true; } }; };`, but complains if you define `kill` as a var (saying it is unused).

Answer (score 3):

There is no good reason to do so.

Either:

- the author doesn't understand that object property names are not variables that need declaring
- they are left over from code that has been deleted
- they have been put in place in (incorrect) anticipation of those variables being used